Cannot close my toggle and transition not working
In my nextjs I have a custom hook and a component. It works and each section opens separately and independently from other sections, so good. But problem (1) I cannot close the "closed" section (it now works that when you open another section, the previous one closes which is good, but I want that you can also close the same section you opened), and problem (2) I added transition with a duration-1000 which does nothing, no clue why?
My custom hook:
import { SetStateAction, useState } from "react";

export default function useOpen() {
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState("closed");
  const open = (sectionName: SetStateAction<string>) =>
    setIsOpened(sectionName);
  return { isOpened, open };
}

My component:
export default function Opendiv() {
  const { isOpened, open } = useOpen();
 return (
    <div>
     <button type="button" onClick={() => open(item.chapter)} className="">
     {isOpened === item.chapter && (
     <div className="transition-all duration-1000 ease-in-out">Opened div, opened div, opened div</div>  
     )}
     </div>);}


Why dont you change toggle logic as below
export default  function useOpen() {
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(null); 
  const open = (sectionName) => {
    setIsOpened((prev) => (prev === sectionName ? null : sectionName));
  };
  return { isOpened, open };
}


thanks but I get this error Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'. Also the transition transition-all duration-1000 ease-in-out does not work still.
